# Execute Oracle SQL command after PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've an SQL file which has some PL/SQL scripts and some DML scripts, but I'm not able to run normal DML commands just after a PL/SQL block IN SQL Developer. For e.g.

```
BEGIN
    -- Some Statements
END;

UPDATE TABLE TABLE_NAME SET FLD_NAME = SOMETHING;
```

Do I need to change anything here so that I can run these commands.

PS: I don't want to put everything in BEGIN ... END block.

Comment: As others have already told you, you need a `/` after the anonymous PL/SQL block. With that in place, your script works as expected (tested in SQL Developer 4). If you still get an error, you need to [edit] your question and provide additional information: the contents of your PL/SQL block, the SQL Developer version you're using, how you run your script (run statement / run script / ... ), the *exact* error message you get etc.

Answer (score 4):

try put `/` after anonymous block:

```
BEGIN
    -- Some Statements
END;
/

UPDATE TABLE TABLE_NAME SET FLD_NAME = SOMETHING;
```